# Test on hardware require Apple ID and Password for IPhone

Tags: codenameone

Is there another way to compile and test it with my Apple ID and the password?
I'm afraid to someone could hitchhike the Apple account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't.

For building the app we need the P12 files and their passwords only.

We offer a wizard that generates them for you and that does require the apple id to generate the certificate. You can change your password after running thru the wizard and force logout everyone who has an old token.

Comment: Perfect. This is very well thought out.